# What is a "grafted" commit in a shallow clone?

Tags: git, git-clone

When doing a shallow clone in git (using the `--depth` option), the root commit is marked as *grafted*.

[image]

Googling didn't lead to any satisfacting documentation.

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with [git grafts](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GraftPoint), which the similar terminology would imply.
Is it just a flag to signal that this commit actually has more parents and isn't the "real" root commit? Or is there something more special about it?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From your link:

> It works by letting users record fake ancestry information for commits. This way you can make git pretend the set of parents a commit has is different from what was recorded when the commit was created.

In a shallow clone, your *root* commit is one that *should* have parents, but not in your repo. So it seems a good use case for grafting.

[In effect](https://git-scm.com/docs/shallow):

> Def.: Shallow commits do have parents, but not in the shallow
> repo, and therefore grafts are introduced pretending that
> these commits have no parents.