# Remove graft mark in git when history becomes available

Tags: git, shallow-clone

I'm experimenting with git shallow clones and wonder if there is any possibility
to "ungraft" a commit if I happen to fetch the parent of an already existing
commit.

Let's say I have a full repo with three commits looking like this (letters
indicating their checksums):

```
A--B--C
```

I then want a shallow clone of only commit C, and perform the following actions:

```
git init
git remote add origin url_to_my_repo
git fetch --depth=1 C
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

This leaves me with a shallow clone of the origin repo, where only commit C is
available. The commit is marked as `grafted`, indicating the broken history.
Let's say I now also fetch commit B in the same way:

```
git fetch --depth=1 B
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

Now it is getting interesting. I have two commits that are both marked
`grafted`. Recalling that each commit records its parent checksum, which can be
successfully verified using e.g. `git cat-file -p C`, Git actually has all
necessary information to replace the grafted mark of commit C with the
*real* history which in fact is available.

In essence, I want the same outcome as if I would checkout commit C with a depth
of 2 in the first place.

I've read [this excellent explanation regarding grafted commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731594/git-shallow-clone-how-do-i-remove-the-grafted-tag-and-what-is-it), however it
requires me to do a manual intervention. I'm sure there must be a command to
tell git to check all grafted commits if the grafted mark can be removed, e.g.
with `git fsck`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Other than `git fetch --unshallow`, there isn't any way to do this today. Probably Git should *automatically* do it on its own (e.g., during `git gc` work), but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading up a bit on the documentation of *shallow* concept, I started to play around with the `shallow`-file located in the `.git`-folder. Essentially it is a list of all commits that are *grafted*. Removing a commit hash in the file successfully "ungrafts" that very commit (i.e. the graft marker is removed, and history viewed correctly in `git log`).

One should be somewhat careful when directly editing anything within the .git-folder, but this at least points in the right direction on how to *ungraft* commits without perform `git fetch --unshallow`.

**Edit:**

I created a python script for this very purpose and recently published it on GitHub, should anyone be interested: https://github.com/chrillof/git-ungraft